# How to import csv files into mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, csv

I am not able to import csv file into mongodb database.
I am using windowsXP 32-bit machine.
I am using `mongoimport --db IPL --collection matches --file C:\Users\Todkar\Desktop\Cambium Networks Full Stack Hiring Challenge\matches.csv`

I am getting error cannot find path specified in OS shell.
see screenshot for more clarification.

[image]

Comment: Is file exists on that directory?

Comment: @Saravana yes it is https://imgur.com/a/RrWrd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

case is where the path involves the use of white space characters, for example, when you need to access the app xyz which location is :

C:\Program Files\ab cd\xyz.exe.

To run this from windows cmd prompt, you need to use

```
C:\"Program Files"\"ab cd"\xyz.exe
```

OR

```
"C:\Program Files\ab cd\xyz.exe"
```

Comment: I need to use this command from OS shell I need to navigate to `C:\ProgramFiles\MongoDB\bin` where mongoimport utility is there am I right ?

Comment: you want to use file specified in `--file C:\Users\Todkar\Desktop\Cambium Networks Full Stack Hiring Challenge\matches.csv` that contains space. but in screenshot your using it without space that does not exists `--file C:\Users\Todkar\Desktop\CambiumNetworksFullStackHiringChallenge\matches.csv`